# Inserting additional items into an inherited list in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, list, django-admin

I'm using some subclasses in my Django app, and I'm continuing that logic through to my admin implementation.

Currently, I have this admin defintion:

```
class StellarObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('title','created_at','created_by','updated_at','updated_by)
```

Now, I have a Planet class, that is a subclass of StellarObject, with an additional field.  I want to add this field to the list_display (not replace StellarObject's display entirely).

If I try something like this:

```
class PlanetAdmin(StellarObjectAdmin):
  list_display.insert(1,'size')
```

I get the following error:

```
name 'list_display' is not defined
```

I will admit, I'm very new to python, and inheritance in general, so I'm sure that there is something simple I am missing.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use:

```
StellarObjectAdmin.list_display.insert(1, 'size')
```

Also, you'll need to change `list_display` from a `tuple` (which is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)) to a `list`. Eg: `list_display = [ ... ]`.

Finally, you'll probably be surprised by what happens: by inserting the item, you're going to be changing the list on `StellarObjectAdmin`. What you probably want to do is:

```
list_display = list(StellarObjectAdmin.list_display) # copy the list
list_display.insert(1, 'size')
```

Which will create a new copy of the list for your `PlanetAdmin` class.

This happens because of the way Python does inheritance. Basically, Python never injects names into a namespace (eg, some languages inject a magic `this` "variable" into methods, while Python forces you to explicitly define the equivalent — `self` — as the first argument of methods), and since a `class` is just another namespace, nothing (like, eg, values in its super classes) gets injected into it.

When you've got a class, `B`, which inherits from another class, `A`, and you try to look up a property on `B` — `B.foo` — it first checks to see if `foo` is in `B`'s namespace, and if it isn't, it goes on to check `A`'s namespace, and so on.

I hope that's clear… If not, I can clarify (or try to find relevant documentation).

Answer (score 1):

David is spot on. Also, as a note, if you want to reference the variable within the class, you'll need to use 'self.'

Example:

```
Class A:
   mylist = [1,2,3]

   def display_list(self):
      for i in self.mylist:
           print i
```